# How to see pictures in your text messages

Tags: sms

I have done what was posted before. When I tape the download button it doesn't download [image][image]

Comment: Please add what phone this is and the texting app you are using.

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy S5. I'm using the texting that comes with the phone

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your mobile data is on and that roaming is switched on. As I do not know your operating system I will post instructions for marshmallow.

Settings > mobile networks > data roaming

EDIT:
based upon the newly supplied facts I viewed you need to change you apn login details as seen on [this website.](http://apn-settings.com/net10-apn-settings-easy-setup-guide/)

Navigate to 
Settings>More>Mobile networks>Access Point Names>Menu>

Once there delete any currently present apn profiles then restart (hold down the power button until the menu including a shut down button appears).

Once turned back on navigate back to the apn menu.

Enter these details in a new profile

APN: tfdata
MMSC: http://mms-tf.net
MMS proxy: mms3.tracfone.com
MMS port: 80

Save and restart once more.

Your MMS should now work.

Comment: That doesn't help. Still can't view pictures sent to me and I still can't send any pictures

Comment: Can you please supply your phone brand and model, operating system and mobile network supplier. Also if this is a recent issue on a new or old phone

Comment: The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S5, not sure what the operating system is, and the net work supplier is NET10.  This is a new issue on my new phone. (Samsung Galaxy S5) My old phone didn't have a problem receiving pictures. It did have a little trouble sending them though.

Comment: Is it net10 AT&T or net10 T-mobile?

Comment: It's NET10 at&t. Why?

Comment: Please see my new edit.

Comment: That didn't work. I still can't receive pictures or send any.

Comment: That's odd. You're certain your mobile data is on when you attempt to send/receive?

Comment: If you have tried all I have suggested you will need to contact your network provider for answers